# Google adds forward slash followed by other file to the search result

Tags: .htaccess, search-engine, google-search

When I search my website on Google it used to add forwarding slash after URL, which I was able to figure out with great stackoverflow forum but I've seen a new problem, where it not only added forwarding slash after url but also a file name following it, see below what it looks like.

> www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/aboutus.php/aboutus.php
>   www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/contactus.php/aboutus.php

Current URL of above are:

> www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/aboutus.php
>   www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/contactus.php

I have some results with only forwarding flash added after URL like below for same site

> www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/aboutus.php/

How do I resolve both problems :

1. adding slash and other random file name in url
2. adding slash after url.

my `.htaccess` looks like below.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.caeoutsourcingservices.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/$1 [L,R=301]
ErrorDocument 400 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 401 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 402 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 405 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 406 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 407 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 408 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 409 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 410 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 411 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 412 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 413 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 414 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 415 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 501 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 502 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 503 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 504 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
ErrorDocument 505 http://www.caeoutsourcingservices.com/sitemap.php
```

Thanks
Manoj Soni

Comment: Visiting those problem pages, it seems like you fixed the problem already.